# Найти слово в файле и напечатать следующую строку Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

У меня есть файл `homework.txt`

В строке n есть следующий текст:

```
function hello():
    var name = 'Dima'
    var age = 15
    var male = 'Male'
```

Как мне узнать всё строки что идут после `:` и которые начинаются с таба?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

`^[ \t]+.*$` - ищет все, что начинается с таба или пробела(или нескольких табов/пробелов)

Comment: слэш поменяйте только.

Comment: Ой да не заметил, сяп @strawdog